# Carto builder, opacity is set at 0 but publishing at 1

Tags: carto, transparency-opacity

I'm working on a Carto map for a client, so I set up a new Carto account for them today.  I'm building it in Carto Builder, using the GUI.  (For this job, I need to just use the GUI, not get into carto.js or writing a whole page.)

I've put in some polygons, set opacity to 0.
But it publishes at opacity 1.  Any idea what I need to do?:

Here's the map

Here's what I see in Carto Builder:
[image]

But here's how it publishes:

[image]

Edit: I'm NOT having the same problem in my old personal Carto account that I've had for years

Comment: Also, a link to the map: https://ccjmaps.carto.com/builder/1c64a21c-3373-46ca-b7a1-75cb08b4e713/embed    

I dont have enough cred to link above

Comment: Two questions. Can you share your CartoCSS code? Have you updated the map as explained [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/publish-share/publishing-and-sharing)?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do anything to this map, though I did report the problem to carto.  A few days later it started displaying correctly.